# How do you write ff (false) as a single character?

Tags: symbols, amsmath

I know that `tt` can be rendered looking like a single character like so: `t\!t`. Unfortunately writing `f\!f` does not work, because to me it looks like it renders the same way as `ff`. So how do I achieve the following result?

[image: f!f]

instead of

[image: ff]

I am using the `align*` environment from the `amsmath` package.

---

Rendered version of `tt`:[image: tt]

Rendered version of `t\!t`: [image: t!t]

Comment: In math mode, `\textit{ff}`, assuming your font supports the `ff` ligature.

Comment: neither `t\!t` nor `f\!f` are a single character, both are two characters with some negative space. How much negative space "looks nice" depends on the font and the person looking. So your first sentence is wrong or misleading.

Comment: @DavidCarlisle after reading the replies and finding the correct solution, this is what I figured too. I'll correct it in my post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Imho it would be better to find a real symbol, but apart from this: use more negative space:

```
\documentclass{article}

\begin{document}

$ff$, $f\!f$, $f\!\!f$ $f\!\!\!f$
\end{document}
```

[image]

Answer (score 3):

I would suggest using the `ff` text ligature, but the appearance is a question of preference.  This answer assumes your italic font supports the `ff` ligature, as shown on the left of the MWE.

I would also note that the spacing in text and math are different, so that using `\!` in text mode also provides a different result, as shown in the center of the MWE.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{mathtools}
\begin{document}
\begin{align*}
  \textit{ff} \ne \textit{f\!f} \ne f\!f
\end{align*}
\end{document}
```

[image]

If `newtxtext` and `newtxmath` are employed...

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Tailor to the specific fonts you're using. The following values are good for Computer Modern math, but not necessarily for other math fonts. Using explicit `mu` units allows for very fine tuning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}

\newcommand{\FF}{f\mspace{-7mu}f}
\newcommand{\TT}{t\mspace{-3mu}t}

\begin{document}

$\TT$

$\FF$

\end{document}
```

[image]

The same values seem almost good for `newtxmath`, but the “tt” requires some more negative kerning.

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{newtxtext,newtxmath}

\newcommand{\FF}{f\mspace{-7mu}f}
\newcommand{\TT}{t\mspace{-3.25mu}t}

\begin{document}

$\TT$

$\FF$

\end{document}
```

[image]

Another math font is `fourier` (based on Utopia) and the values need to be different:

```
\documentclass{article}
\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{fourier}

\newcommand{\FF}{f\mspace{-7mu}f}
\newcommand{\TT}{t\mspace{-5.25mu}t}

\begin{document}

$\TT$

$\FF$

\end{document}
```

[image]